# MVVM use of INotifyPropertyChanged Model not notifying ViewModel

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to use MVVM for the first time.  I have a Windows Phone app (Mango), which has a model class, a view model class, and a view xaml page.  I have controls (textboxes) bound to the VM, and the VM is bound to the Model.

Both the model and the view model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  The implementation I'm using is copied, so that I could use it to try to figure out what I'm doing with INPC.  Here is the code that is listed in both classes:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
   }
}
```

I have one property in the Model class that can be either set manually (from a textbox) or calculated (by changing one of the other properties).  Let's call that one Result.

If I change one of the other properties, and step through, INPC is invoked in both the changed property and the recalculated property in the Model class, although `PropertyChanged` is `null`, so that portion of the code is skipped.  Then in the VM, the property that was changed steps through that class' INPC (as part of the set accessor), and this time `PropertyChanged` is not `null`, so the `PropertyChanged` method is invoked.  For the `Result` property, however, INPC is not raised (that property doesn't have INPC invoked by the other property's set accessor).

Here is one of the properties in the Model, which is not the calculated property:

```
public int AgeSetting
{
   get
   {
      return (int)GetValueOrDefault(AgeSettingKeyName, AgeSettingDefault);
   }
   set
   {
      AddOrUpdateValue(AgeSettingKeyName, value);
      Calculate();
   }
}
```

Here is the property of the Calculated value in the Model.

```
public int PointsSetting
{
   get
   {
      return (int)GetValueOrDefault(PointsSettingKeyName, PointsSettingDefault);
   }
   set
   {
      AddOrUpdateValue(PointsSettingKeyName, value);
   }
}
```

From the ViewModel, here are both properties:

```
public int Age
{
   get
   {
      return person.AgeSetting;
   }
   set
   {
      person.AgeSetting = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");
   }
} 

public int PointsAllowed
{
   get
   {
      return person.PointsSetting;
   }
   set
   {
      person.PointsSetting = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("PointsAllowed");
   }
}
```

Having never done this before, I was expecting that INPC should bubble up from the model class, to the VM class, to the UI.  It doesn't appear to be working that way.

I know that the Result (calculated) property is changing, as I can navigate away from the page and come back, and the newly displayed value is correct.  I just don't know how to get from the calculated value in the model, to the view model, and up to the view.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: One helpful tool is the output window in VS.  That will tell you if any bindings fail when you start your app/initialize your UI.  It may be your binding that is incorrect.

Comment: I was not aware of that.  Thank you.  The binding is working, however, because it does pull the value that is stored in the isolatedstoragesettings into the textbox

Comment: I don't have time to figure out what you're really asking, so could you please do me a fav and [edit your title](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7421606/edit) so that it is an actual question with some relation to what you're asking?  Bonus points for only using tags organically.  Thanks!

Comment: Using tags organically.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the value of a calculated property changes, also raise the PropertyChanged event for that property. This means that when a single property changes, there might be events fired for multiple properties.

Also, if it's possible/smart in your design, you could bind directly to model properties and make the Model a property of your ViewModel. This decrease code maintenance by a lot.

Comment: +1. I can't see the point of having a ViewModel on a class that already implements INotifyPropertyChanged, unless other MVVM features are needed (ie it is pointless adapting something that you can already bind to perfectly well).

Comment: Thank you both.  Yes, Bas, I can see where I may need to fire for multiple properties.  I thought it was automatic when something changed in the M, the VM would see it.  Also, yes, I could go straight from V to M, but the point of this exercise was to learn MVVM.  I haven't done it before, so wanted to try it.  I think the key, though, is what Maxim said below, about an event handler, and subscribing (things I don't know, so will search), but my VM is not "subscribed" to M, it just gets/sets properties of an instance of the M.  I'm thinking that's where I need to look.

Comment: Generally, in MVVM, you woldn't have the Model classes notify at all. The Model is just logical, and is accessed / modified by the View Model. Basically, the Model never changes unless directed to do so by the View Model (similar to the Model / Controler interractiion in MVC). Example, the ViewModel may tell the Model to load data from the data base, and then the ViewModel will notify when data load is complete.

Comment: Yes, that's why the "if possible/smart", it's not the most clean way in domain driven development, but it will save a lot of time.

Comment: I ended up eliminating the MV in this case.  There was no real need for it, as it just passed the model through to the view.  I will be using a modelview in another part of the app, but for this part, it really is not necessary.  I was trying to use it just because I've never used mvvm before (nor have I used MVC), but it really isn't needed here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For properties that are dependant on the values of other properties, it's up the programmer to notify that multiple properties have changed.

Given a class with three properties - Score, Multiplier, and Total - where Total is dependant on the values of Score and Multiplier, I can write the class like so:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private int score;
    public int Score
    {
        get
        {
            return this.score;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.score != value)
            {
                this.score = value;
                // Notify that this property has changed
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Score);
                // Notify that a dependant property has changed
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Total);
            }
        }
    }

    private int multiplier;
    public int Multiplier
    {
        get
        {
            return this.multiplier;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.multiplier != value)
            {
                this.multiplier = value;
                // Notify that this property has changed
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Multiplier);
                // Notify that a dependant property has changed
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Total);
            }
        }
    }

    public int Total
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Score * this.Multiplier;
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice, for instance, that when I set the value of Score, I notify that both Score and Total have changed. Your specific implimentation of NotifyOfPropertyChange will look different from mine, but the central idea is the same. Because Total is a propert dependant on the values of other properties, it never notifies. Instead the properies upon which Total is dependant on are responsible for notifying.

Answer (score 1):

In the model, in setter of the calculated property call NotifyPropertyChanged method. Some logic in your app should be updating the model. Make sure that the ViewModel is subscribed to this event. This is very important, since I think this is exactly what you are missing here.

Then, in the EventHandler in ViewModel, that was subscribed to a Models on PropertyChanged event, change the appropriate property value of the ViewModel (here method in the view model updates the property in the view model), that the UI is bound to.

Comment: In my model, any time the properties are changed, the NPC method is called, though it is not in the setter, but in another method that is called from the setter (the method that saves the values to isostore).  I have stepped through, and that method gets called.  What I may be missing, however, is the event handler you speak of.  I am not sure what you mean by "subscribed to a model's on PropertyChanged" event, so I will look into that.  As it is, my VM Properties just pull from an instance of the model.  That may be the key.  I'll look into that.  Thanks!

Comment: If, for example, you model has a public event PropertyChanged, then your view model should A) have a reference to a model B) at some point subscribe to this event. Like model.PropertyChanged += OnModelChanged; In OnModelChanged set the value of a public property that the UI is bound to. This way the notification link will be complete.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the model class.  Without this your event handler will be null when being called.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // Stuff
}

public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // Stuff
}
```

Also check out my blog here on some MVVM stuff. I have some tutorials as well as some ways to fire Inotify without using string values (use reflection instead).

Comment: I looked at your blog post.  I have not yet tried to implement it, but I believe I will.  I like the way you use reflection to get the name of the changed property.  In this case, though, I decided that the best way to go was to eliminate the modelview for this view.  I looked at it, and in this case, the modelview is doing nothing but passing the model to the view.  Thanks for the tips.